# Passing html elements from php to javascript in an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a code in which I am giving an ajax call to the server.

```
function getMouseHoverData(param) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../AP/APdocsged.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            //async:false,
            data: {
                'isAjax': true,
                'param': param

            },
            success: function (response) {
                var res=response;
document.write(res)    ;


            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the server side code:

```
if(isset($_POST['isAjax']) && (true == $_POST['isAjax'])){
    $oArqv = new gdmdocs('gdmdocs.id_arqv = '.$_POST['param'], false, 'gdmdocs.id_arqv', true);


    $myArray=$oArqv->DOC_TITLE[0];

        echo (htmlentities($myArray));

    exit;
}
```

Now what is stored in myArray is an HTML image. On doing echo I get this as result:

```
&lt;table border=0 cellspacing=0 .............
```

However the problem is when i try to print this in the javascript success 
ajax response I dont get any output.

Also what i tried was

```
$myArray=$oArqv->DOC_TITLE;
```

instead of

```
$myArray=$oArqv->DOC_TITLE[0];
```

Then what happens is I get a response like

```
function() Array {[native]}
```

I am very new to this, so it would be very helpful if someone gives an idea on how to pass this information from php to javascript

Comment: `when i try to print this in the javascript success ajax response i dont get any output` - do you mean nothing appears in the DOM?

Comment: No. Neither the document.write gets executed nor an alert box. However if I pass array(DOC_TITLE[]) instead of DOC_TITLE[0], I get an alert box in success but it shows function() Array{[native]}.

Comment: _"On doing echo I get this as result: <table border=0..."_. That's a PHP error, you should look at what it says. If you're using Chrome, you can open your Developer tools using the F12 key, and go to the _Network_ tab. Then, reload your page or trigger the Ajax call again, and find that call in the list. Click on it, and then on _Preview_, on the right. That should make it easier for you to debug.

Comment: Actually that's not an error, it is returning the same information which is there in the HTML image(DOC_TITLE[0]) in the form of html tags. But those html tags are not being passed to the javascript.

Comment: Better formating

Comment: `Now what is stored in myArray is an HTML image.` No, it's an HTML table, based on the output that you posted.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `htmlentities` on something that is expected to be HTML. You call `htmlentities` on things that are NOT expected to be HTML, in order to escape any characters that are special in HTML.

Comment: Yes I agree that was just for trial purpose. If i remove the htmlentities , then also I dont get any output. Also, that is an HTML table, sorry for using HTML image. But, still the question remains the same :-)